# Question regarding plotting 95% Intervals using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have a data frame with several columns and I need to draw boxplots and a some kind of an interval plot (with 2.5% and 97.5%) for each column.

My data set looks like this:

```
set.seed(123)
x1=rnorm(100,0,1)
x2=rnorm(100,0,0.5)
x3=rnorm(100,0,0.6)
data_x=data.frame(x1,x2,x3)
```

I was able to draw the boxplots for this data using following lines of code:

```
datax_long=data_x %>% gather(x ,value ,x1:x3)
ggplot(data=datax_long, aes(y= x, x=value, fill=x))+ geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

Now I need to draw a interval plot for each column. It is kind of a horizontal line from 2.5%th percentile to 97.5%th percentile. The range of values for each variable should roughly the same as in the boxplot.

Is this something we can do using `ggplot2` package in `R` ?

Thank you

Comment: The 95% confidence interval for the mean is not the same thing as the 2.5% and 92.5% quantiles of the whole vector. These are different concepts. Why would you expect them to be the same?

Comment: @AllanCameron Yes you are correct. What I actually want is to plot the 2.5%th and 97.5% percentiles. So that the range of the box plot and  the error bar plot is roughly same. I thought error bar plot can do that. That is wrong. Actually, error bar plot  show the true values. (mean(x1) +/-(1.96*sd(x1)/10)  )

Comment: @AllanCameron I edited the question. Hope it make more sense now. Thank you  very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
ggplot(datax_long, aes(x = value, y = x)) +
  stat_summary(geom = "errorbarh", 
               fun.min = function(z) quantile(z, .025), 
               fun = mean,
               fun.max = function(z) quantile(z, 0.975), color = "red") +
  stat_summary(geom = "point", fun = mean, color = "blue")
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I want. Can you tell how to add a legend also (like in the boxplot above) ? I tried fill=x. But it didnt work. Thank you once again.

Comment: Nothing is filled here. `aes(color = x)` (and deleting the constant colors) should get you a legend.